# Writing to a file in unix not working; in windows it works

Tags: java, unix, io

Given:

```
try{
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(someFileName);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("Hello Java");
}catch...
}finally{
bw.close();
}
```

It works perfectly in windows, but not in Unix.
Remark: the created file in unix has the complete 777 rights!

What should I do to get it working in unix?

Thanks,
Roxana

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: what is `out` here..please give full code

Comment: Try `bw.write("Hello UNIX")` then

Comment: The stuff in the `catch` is quite important, and "doesn't work" isn't helpful; post the stack trace of the exception you're getting.

Comment: i didn't get any exception, that's why I didn't know what's wrong - in the end, teh answer was the missing bw.flush()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a

```
bw.flush();
```

before closing the file (on try block).

Maybe the information is still on the buffer, so it doesn't get reflected on the file contents

Answer (score 2):

You should give us some more code, specially the section where the someFileName is specified. Since there is some difference in Java on how the 'file separator' is treated, your problem could be that you're creating/opening a file in windows, but it isn't on the unix... and your 'catch' is treating it, but you didn't provide its contents.

Take [a look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

> "file.separator" --> Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.

Comment: that is something that I know - the problem was a '.flush()' missing:)

Comment: that's why people always ask for full code here, or more message erros, etc... it's impossible to guess what you know and what you don't.

Comment: true, true:) sometimes I forget that not all the people know me..:) anyway, thanks for the reply. I voted for it, because in other situations, it may be 'The Answer':)

Comment: :) yep, that was just a comment :)